# C# DataGridView with custom EditingControl: how to hand over new/changed value to corresponding cell?

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell

I am currently working on a C# DataGridView application where I need to introduce custom EditingControls. So far so good, custom Editing Control appears when I enter the corresponding cell, and I can edit the value in this control. But unfortunately, after leaving the custom Editing Control, the corresponding cell does not take over the edited value but still shows the old value. Maybe I am blind, but I can't see any point where I can/need to update the cell's value from the Editing Control's code. Can someone bring some light into the dark? Thanks!
FYI: I followed this [MS example]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: It is in the method OnValueChanged().  Add break points and see which event you are getting to.  Then figure out why you are not getting to all the events.

Comment: You didn't follow that example properly. I copied the code from that page and it worked exactly as expected for me. The value is transferred back to the cell via the `EditingControlFormattedValue` property. The editing control doesn't push the value to the cell. The cell pulls the value from the editing control.